# Laravel - verification mail non object

Tags: php, object, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to send an verification mail:

This is my mail:

```
  {{ URL::to('/user/confirm', array($confirmation_code)) }}<br/>
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/user/confirm/{confirmation_code}', 'UserController@confirmEmail');
```

Controller:

```
    public function confirmEmail() {
      $user = User::find(Input::get('confirmation_code'));

      if($user->confirmation_code !== Input::get('confirmation_code'))
      {
              // Redirect to error page or something
              return Response::error('404');
      }
      // Activate the user and clear the validation key
      $user->confirmed = 1;
      $user->confirmation_code = '';
      $user->save();
      // display success message
    return View::make('pages.home');
}
```

Why is it saying: "Trying to get property of non-object" at this line:

```
if($user->confirmation_code !== Input::get('confirmation_code'))
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it could not find a user in this line:

```
$user = User::find(Input::get('confirmation_code'));
```

Make sure your confirmation code is correct:

```
dd( Input::get('confirmation_code') );
```

Also, is `confirmation_code` this really your user primary key (id)?

You may have to do something like:

```
$user = User::where('confirmation_code', Input::get('confirmation_code'))->first();
```